# Node Express MySQL and the Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

I am working with Node.js, Express.js, and a MySQL database.  Within the database I have posts that I would like to display using Pug.js view engine. I got it to work by connecting to the database and rendering the home route correctly but I am apparently making a second callback because I get the Error:

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

I am unsure of how to fix this without breaking it further because it actually renders as expected now. Here is what I am working with:

app.js:

```
// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){

  //get posts from database to show on news section.
  var postList =  [];

  db.query('SELECT * from articles', function(err, rows) {

    if(err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      //missing the img fields
      var post = {
        'id':rows[i].id,
        'title':rows[i].title,
      }
      //Add the newly created post object to the postList array
      postList.push(post);

      //THE ERROR IS PROBABLY BECAUSE OF THIS \/

      res.render('index', {
        title:'mySite',
        page: 'News',
        postList: postList});
    }
  });
});
```

here is the index.pug:

```
extends layout

block content
  table
    for post in postList
      tr
        td
          h3 #{post.title}
        td
          p #{post.id}
```

Once again it renders fine but the terminal is throwing the error at me and i would prefer to fix it if possible.
I have tried to pull the res.render for the index out of the query like this:

```
// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){

  //get posts from database to show on news section.
  var postList =  [];

  db.query('SELECT * from articles', function(err, rows) {

    if(err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      //missing the img fields
      var post = {
        'id':rows[i].id,
        'title':rows[i].title,
      }
      //Add the newly created post object to the postList array
      postList.push(post);

    }
  });
      //THIS FIXES THE ERROR \/

      res.render('index', {
        title:'mySite',
        page: 'News',
        postList: postList});
      //THIS NO LONGER RENDERS THE postList ARRAY
});
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost made it right, man! but the `render` should be inside `db.query` such as

```
//get posts from database to show on news section.
  var postList = [];

  db.query('SELECT * from articles', function (err, rows) {

    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      //missing the img fields
      var post = {
        'id': rows[i].id,
        'title': rows[i].title,
      }
      //Add the newly created post object to the postList array
      postList.push(post);

    } // end for loop

    res.render('index', {
      title: 'mySite',
      page: 'News',
      postList: postList
    });
  });
```

The explanation is `db.query` is callback function, if you put `res.render` outside it, javascript engine will execute it first so you will get nothing in your `postList`. So, you must wait until `db.query` finish and populate your `postList` then render it.

Why you got **Can't set headers after they are sent** because you execute `res.render` multiple times (you put it inside the loop). It must be executed just once.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow... thanks for this I cant believe i didn't see that >_<